# Html com laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tenho um botão no meu index. Quero chamar outro página como faço no laravel 5.2 ? Seria através das rotas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correto é utilizar a estrutura do `MVC` indo pelo `Controller`

Na sua **View**:

```
<a href="pagina">Ir</a>
...
```

No arquivo **routes.php**:

```
Route::get('pagina', 'SeuController@redireciona');
```

E no seu **SeuController**:

```
public function redireciona()
{
    //Manda para view responsável pela página
    return view('suaview');
}
```